# objects of type collection cannot be serialized

Tags: peoplesoft

I'm writing an App Engine which has two steps so far:
1) a method that retrieves a collection (ApiObject) from a level 1 scroll in a component interface and returns it.
2) a method that, given a collection, inserts it into a level 1 scroll in a component interface.

the App Engine seems to be working but the log shows these warnings:

Objects of class CI_OPR_DEFN_OPR_DEF_TBL_RCCollection cannot be serialized. (2,694)
 Message Set Number: 2
 Message Number: 694
 Message Reason: Objects of class CI_OPR_DEFN_OPR_DEF_TBL_RCCollection cannot be serialized. (2,694)

Failed to serialize an object of class CI_OPR_DEFN_OPR_DEF_TBL_RCCollection. (2,275)
 Message Set Number: 2
 Message Number: 275
 Message Reason: Failed to serialize an object of class
CI_OPR_DEFN_OPR_DEF_TBL_RCCollection. (2,275)

the problem is, I need these warnings to not be shown in the log.
Does anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks

EDIT: I already figured it out. The problem is that the ApiObject was declared as global in order to use the same one in both steps.
Does anyone know how to pass a collection from one step to another without using AETs?

Answer (score 1):

About passing the ApiObject trough steps in the AE you can try to create an App Package class, and use it in your entire AE, the App Package will be global, and not your ApiObject.